# How to make all gridlines/borders consistent in Microsoft Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report

I have this really frustrating problem that may or may not be fixable due to an access technicality, but I'm going to ask anyway.

On a report, I have multiple subreports that display a list of documents; and the information within those subreports are outlined by a grid, so that it looks like the documents are in a table.

My problem is, if I have the border of these objects too close, then sometimes the gridline/border outline is thicker in some areas and not in others. Why is this? It's making the report look really inconsistent and unpresentable.

The only way to combat this, is to leave a space between the object and the border section of the form. But then this means the documents are split and look like they are in their own tables, rather than one big table if this makes sense?

I can't seem to find any solutions to this at all. I'd be very grateful if you know how to fix this or can provide an alternative solution!

Please see the attached images:

**UPDATE:** I'd just like to add, that when I view the report in 'Report View'; it is presented correctly. This inconsistency only appears when I view it in 'Print view' or if I export it.

[image: This shows what the report looks like if I leave a gap between the objects and the form border. Creating a table that's split between each document, but the lines are consistent in width/colour/boldness]

[image: This image shows that when I leave no gaps, the table looks connected and complete. However, some of the lines are thicker/bolder than others.]

[image: I am unable to overlap the documents because it is only one object that represents all of the documents from a table]

Comment: Rather than having them just touch, have you tried overlapping them slightly? With the item selected in design view, ctrl + directional arrows will nudge the control 1 pixel at a time.

Comment: @MattHall Unfortunately, because it is a report; in design view there is only one object to represent all of the documents; because of this, I can't make them overlap. I will upload a picture to try and illustrate what I mean

Comment: Oh ok. Perhaps make the borders of the fields transparent and then use the line control to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @MattHall Hi Matt. Just tried this idea, but it seems that the documents are able to expand downwards depending on the amount of characters in the field. Whereas the line doesn't expand downwards, so it just looks like a bunch of small lines placed around everywhere if that makes sense?

Comment: I wonder if changing the vertical anchor position of the line would help? I.e put it to the bottom and should appear rooted to the bottom of the the detail section (i.e. each row of data).

Comment: @MattHall I added a horizontal line underneath the objects and that works fine. It separates the rows horizontally. However, the vertical line that separates the columns doesn't expand with the objects. So vertically it doesn't work. I'm going to attempt to VBA code it so that it can expand with the objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103308/discussion-between-alex-and-matt-hall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a **simple** answer as to why access creates these inconsistencies. However, I did find a workaround which solves the issue.

Used this as a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221362(v=office.11).aspx

- Add a horizontal line underneath the objects on the report. This will separate the document rows
- To get the vertical lines, I had to insert them via VBA code. This is because I was unable to get vertical lines to expand when the objects grow

  ```
   Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
   Dim ctrl As Control
   Dim intLineMargin As Integer

   ' This is the spacing between the right edge of the
   ' control and the Vertical Seperation Line
   intLineMargin = 0
  ```

Loop through each control in the detail section of the subreport by selecting their Tags. The first object (Document) has an extra step, because you need vertical lines on both the left and right side.

First if statement creates the line on the left and right side for all controls with the tag `"DocumentName"` (In this case, only the first object)

```
    For Each ctrl In Me.Section(acDetail).Controls
        With ctrl

            If ctrl.Tag = "DocumentName" Then

                Me.Line (0, 0)-(0, 0 + .Height + 150)
    
                Me.Line ((.Left + .Width), 0)-(.Left + .Width + intLineMargin, .Height + 150)
            End If
```

The rest of the objects have the tag `"DocumentDetails"`, and only need vertical lines on the **RIGHT** side of them. The if statement creates these vertical lines:

```
        If ctrl.Tag = "DocumentDetails" Then
        Me.Line ((.Left + .Width), 0)-(.Left + .Width + intLineMargin, .Height + 150)
        End If

    End With
Next

Set ctrl = Nothing


End Sub
```

**Result:**
All lines are now consistent

[image: Consistent table lines]

Comment: Cool. I must try this with a report of mine that has similar problems. Questions/Notes: 1. I wonder about `intLineMargin` - if it is <>0 you'll get slanted vertical lines, won't you? 2. Is `+ 150` to avoid tiny gaps at the bottom of each record? 3. Have you tried `Me.Section(acDetail).Height` instead of `ctrl.Height + 150` ? It might be more exact.

Comment: @Andre 1. If intLineMargin is higher than 0, then yes, the lines become slanted. 2. Yes, although I find that it varies depending on the size of the object; so it doesn't always fix the tiny gaps. 3. No I haven't, although I'm not sure how I would implement that? I use ctrl because I'm altering the attributes of individual objects and not the whole of the acDetail section

Comment: @Andre 3. - Sorry, I see what you mean now. I tried it, but it sets the line height to the height of the detail section as if it was in 'design view'. So the line isn't expanding when multiple data is brought in and viewed in 'print view'

Comment: 3. ah, I see. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MS Access 2021 still has problems with buggy implementation of table gridlines and the Arrange Tabular functionality. Thanks for the code that helps with a solution. I've developed it a bit further into a subroutine that can be shared throughout a MS Access project.

To call this subroutine from a Class module of a report, you need to  create an On Print event for a section (usually the Detail section) that you want to draw a table (around fields) in.

Example code for the on print event of the Detail section could be:

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    DrawReportTableGridlines Me, Me.Detail, -2, 10
End Sub
```

Then you need to set the Tag value to "DrawRightBorder" in any control that you want a vertical right border beside. The top, bottom and far left borders will be added automatically.

The table gridlines will only be visible in Print Preview.

```
Public Sub DrawReportTableGridlines(ByRef targetReport As Report, ByRef targetSection As Section, Optional ByVal lngBorderColor As Long = -1, Optional ByVal lngBorderWidth As Long = -1)
  
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim lngFarLeftEdge As Long
    Dim lngFarRightEdge As Long
    Dim lngCtrlRightEdge As Long
    lngFarLeftEdge = 0
    lngFarRightEdge = 0
    
    ' instead of passing a long integer for a specific colour, a simple default colourcan be used, as below
    If lngBorderColor = -1 Then
        lngBorderColor = RGB(214, 220, 229)   ' very light grey
    ElseIf lngBorderColor = -2 Then
        lngBorderColor = RGB(127, 127, 127)    ' light grey
    End If
    
    ' default border width is hairline. If the user has passed something else as a parameter then change to that
    ' FYI: apparently, if you try to change a width back from something thicker to hairline you get some inconsistent results
    If lngBorderWidth <> -1 Then
      targetReport.DrawWidth = lngBorderWidth
    End If
        
    For Each ctrl In targetSection.Controls
        targetReport.Line (0, 0)-(0, 0 + targetReport.Height), lngBorderColor ' draw far left vertical border of the section
        With ctrl
            lngCtrlRightEdge = .Left + .Width    ' find the position of the right hand edge ofthis control
            ' if the control's tag contains the text DrawRightBorder then draw a righthand border.
            ' NB The control's Tag could contain other information, too, if wanted, so use InStr instead of just a straight =
            If InStr(1, ctrl.Tag, "DrawRightBorder", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                targetReport.Line (lngCtrlRightEdge, 0)-(lngCtrlRightEdge, targetReport.Height), lngBorderColor   ' Draw a vertical border at the right hand side of the control
            End If
        If lngFarLeftEdge > .Left Then lngFarLeftEdge = .Left    ' eventually this will hold the leftmost edge position
        If lngFarRightEdge < lngCtrlRightEdge Then lngFarRightEdge = lngCtrlRightEdge    ' eventually this will hold the rightmost edge position
        End With
        targetReport.Line (lngFarLeftEdge, 0)-(lngFarLeftEdge, targetReport.Height), lngBorderColor   ' Draw a vertical border at the leftmost edge of the table fields
    Next
    
    ' Draw horizontal line at the top and bottom of each row - simpler than testing for newpage and only doing a topline at the top of a page
    ' the thiskness doesn't seem to be doubled - perhaps the top of the section is the sameas the bottom of the previous section
    ' or perhaps it just works for hairline thickness lines. i haven't tested.
    targetReport.Line (lngFarLeftEdge, 0)-(lngFarRightEdge, 0), lngBorderColor
    targetReport.Line (lngFarLeftEdge, targetReport.Height)-(lngFarRightEdge, targetReport.Height), lngBorderColor

    Set ctrl = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Note that, if the lines are anything other than hairline width then the outer lines surrounding the table will generally be half the thickness of the internal grid lines. This is because they are placed exactly on the edge of the section so only the side of the line inside the section gets printed. However, in practice, it's not that easilly noticeable. The table still looks clean and consistent. If it's an issue for you, you could add some more code to fix this.

Some issues that this solution doesn't fix:
The borders that this subroutine draws are often (but not always) partly overwritten where a control is given a shaded background or formatting is added to it via the Conditional Formatting feature in Design View.

Some workarounds are:

- Set the BackColor for the whole section rather than for individual controls, via the on format event for the section. Or,
- Use HTML to highlight or colour just the text but not the whole cell

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what would happen if you make the subreports be in datasheet view?

Otherwise I'd normally play around with line thicknesses, and make sure the control, section and subform heights were set exactly, and use the align tool to push your subreports together.

Or, as a last resort, I'd scrap the whole thing and load the pieces into a table and then make a subreport based off that.  But I don't know what your stipulations are.

Comment: I've played around with the thickness, height, and various other properties but there is always some inconsistency in the report. 

I'm not sure why, because some of them align correctly and some don't; which doesn't make sense because their properties are all set through one object (so it's not like I've made a human error on each one)

The subreports have been created based on tables; all of the data that they display are from tables that have already been created